# Overwrite current Ubuntu partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu already installed. I am currently downloading Ubuntu 12.04 and wish to replace the Ubuntu partition which already exists, with the new ISO.

I am currently at the screen where it shows all the different partitions and mount points. I can see there are a few NFTS partitions representing my RAID 0 Windows 7 OS. What im not sure is what I need to do to replace the Ubuntu 10 partition on here? There are so many different partitions I am not sure what to do and to which partition.

I have:

/dev/mapper/isw_dcidgaidc_Linux

/dev/mapper/isw_dcidgaidc_Linux1   ext4     60628MB unknown

/dev/mapper/isw_dcidgaidc_Linux5   swap     2628MB  0MB

/dev/mapper/isw_dcidgaidc_Linux1   ext4     60628MB unknown

/dev/mapper/isw_dcidgaidc_Linux2p1 swap     2628MB  0MB

/dev/mapper/isw_dcidgaidc_Linux5   swap     2628MB  unknown

Comment: Are you looking to start with a fresh OS, or there is the possibility of doing a `dist-upgrade` that will upgrade your version without having to re-install everything...

Comment: @Kruug I just went to do that, but when I boot into Ubuntu either my version 10 says no root file system is defined? I have grub on here to manage a dual boot with Windows 7. I'd like to keep this ideally. The whole thing is on a RAID 0.

I think I need to put the installation CD in again and set one of the above partition roots to be /.

Comment: Would you have more benefit posting this on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange site? http://askubuntu.com/